# Getting message in SQL Informational: The full-text search condition contained noise word(s)

Tags: sql

After replacing the search string I am getting this message in a SQL stored procedure:

```
SET SearchString = replace(SearchString, '&quot', '""')
```

Informational: The full-text search condition contained noise word(s).

Comment: could any one please help me in this

Comment: Tag dbms used, since this is a product specific question. (Also add procedure code, at least the important part, etc.)

Comment: For search string I am passing &quot instead of double quote in store procedure parameter and i am replacing it before passing it to FREETEXTTABLE

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not a specific database product.